# How to run a function only when key is held?

Tags: c#

0 = Standing Still , 1 = Moving

The address's default values are 0, but changes to 1(default speed) when you are moving(holding W).

When I change the address to 10, it makes me move forward forward at speed 10, but when I tap W, it resets to 1.

When I constantly change the address to 10, it does not let you stop moving because 0 means not moving and it never lets you get to 0.

The program changes the movement speed in-game.

You cant stop moving when the program is ran.

I am unsure on how to read when the W key is held down as I would like to make the program only run when the W key is held.

I have tried mostly everything, although it is probable that it is due to my own error.

Here is the program that constantly sets your speed to the number your input.

```
    static void SpeedSpeed()
    {
        VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("ac_client");

        string StringSpeed = "";
        StringSpeed = Console.ReadLine();
        int NumberSpeed = Int32.Parse(StringSpeed);

        int LocalPlayer = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)PlayerBase);

        int address1010 = LocalPlayer + Speed;

        //code to run when W is held.
        while (true)
        {
            vam.WriteInt32((IntPtr)address1010, NumberSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have one objective here and that is to have the speed(address1010) be constantly changed to the number the user inputs(NumberSpeed) but ONLY when the key W is held down.

Expected - 
       1. You start the thread(SpeedSpeed) through another thread(MainThread).

```
   2. It asks you in the console to input a number from 0 to 10 from MainThread.

   3. I input 10.

   4. I go in-game and hold down the W key, which activates the program

   5. I move forward, as the program makes me do.

   6. I let go of the W key.

   7. The program stops until the W key is held again.
```

Actual - 
       1. You start the thread(SpeedSpeed) through another thread(MainThread).

```
   2. It asks you in the console to input a number from 0 to 10 from MainThread.

   3. I input 10.

   4. I go in-game and I am constantly moving forward and can't stop.
```

Comment: You providing little information... But maybe you could do something with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using keyPressed

```
 bool mIsPress = false;

 yourControl.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed);

 private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W)
    {
         mIspress= true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }else{
         mIspress= false;
     }
 }
```

After this you can create a thread

```
if(mIsPress){
   //your code to run
 }else{
   //your code to stop
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a DLL import.
It makes it much easier

This is the link I used to solve my similar problem

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAsyncKeyState.html

I am certain this link will help you

When you use this you must put in `using System.Runtime.InteropServices`